# Python - Person object with expanding list

Tags: python, list, function, class, oop

I am looking into classes and OOP structures in Python, trying to solve the following problem:

> Given a text file of the form:
>
> ```
> Name: [someName]        Course: [someCourse]
> Name: [someName]        Course: [someCourse]
> ...
> ```
>
> Containing the [NAME] of a student and a [COURSE] taken by this
>   student. We assume no two student have the same name, hence:
>
> ```
> Name: Anderson      Course: Biology
> Name: Peter         Course: History
> Name: Anderson      Course: Mathematics
> ```
>
> Indicates that Anderson takes both Biology AND Mathematics.
>
> **The problem**:
>
> - Read input file
> - Extract student name and course
> - Print out a summary of the courses taken by a particular student
>
> For instance, the results based on the example file above, ought to
>   generate:
>
> ```
> Student: Anderson
> Courses: Biology
>          Mathematics
>
> Student: Peter
> Courses: History
> ```

**What I have so far**:

I have been able to read the file and extract information about both name and course. I have added these values into two lists(arrays), **student_name** and **student_course**. From the example text file above, this would yield the following lists:

```
student_name = ["Anderson", "Peter", "Anderson"]
student_course = ["Biology", "History", "Mathematics"]
```

Meaning that the indexes correspond. That is, the student located at **student_name[i]** takes the course located at **student_course[i]**.

I also have a Student class with the following structure:

```
class Student(object):
    #Variables here
    student_list = [] #empty list of students

    def __init__(self, name, course):
        self.name = name
        self.course = course

    def check_student(self, name, course):
        """ 
            Checks if student (given by name) is already in student list.
            Function already_exists() works! 
        """
        if(self.already_exists(self.name) == false): #If not in list
            self.student_list.append(self.name) #Add student to list
            ##### NEED help HERE ####
            #Add course to already existing Student. 
        else:
            ##### NEED help HERE ####
            #Create student + add course.
```

The idea is to loop through both the **student_name** and **student_course** lists, to update the student information. That is, if new name is encountered: add it to the student_list, and note the course. Contrastingly, if name already exists: simply add the course to the student.

**The Question**:

Any help on how I can add a course to an already existing student object, or create a new student altogether, is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a student_list on the Student class, I think you would be better to have a separate "Students" class.

The Students class can maintain a map of student name to Student instance.

Each individual Student instance can then be solely responsible for maintaining it's list of course names.

Depending on the desired order of the output, you may want to also maintain an array of Student instances on the Students class. However the map would still be useful to efficiently lookup a Student instance given a student name

Comment: *The Students class can maintain a map of student name to Student instance.* in that case, why not just make 1 single dict and leave out the Students class

Comment: The way the question is phrased, I suspect that they want to output in the order that the names appeared in the input. Therefore, keeping an array of students in the order they are added will make producing the final output easier. That said having Students as a class is probably overkill, unless you wanted to deal with multiple sets of Students

Comment: Thank you. My dictionary however, seems to ignore a pair of elements, when feeding it two lists. I have the lists: 

    student_name = ["Anderson", "Peter", "Anderson", "Bastian"]
    course_list = ["Biology", "History", "Maths", "History]

When using a for-loop and assigning my_dict[student_names[i]] = course_list[i], the final result ignores the pair (Anderson/Biology). 

Why is that?

Comment: A dictionary is a mapping between a key and a value. Within a dictionary each key is unique, and so when you assign to the key "Anderson" for the second time with the value "Maths" you are overwriting the first value of "Biology". This is why your key should be a student name, and the value should be an instance of a Student. A Student should be a class that consists of a name and a list of courses. Then instead of assigning to the value when iterating over the lists of names and courses, you should create an instance if it doesn't exist, and otherwise add to the existing instance of Student.